# Contextually injecting static class properties in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I'm writing a website generator with various classes that represent the content in the webpages such as `Page`, `NewsPost`, `Tag`, `Category` etc.

I'd like to be able to construct these objects plainly, and I don't have a problem with that.

However, I'd also like to construct these objects within a certain context - say, the context of a website with a particular root URL. Let's say I put this context into an instance of a class `ContentManager`. This is the code I ultimately hope to end up with:

```
page = Page(title='Test Page', content='hello world!')
assert page.cm == None

cm = ContentManager(root_url='//localhost')
page = cm.Page(title='Test Page', content='hello world!') 
assert page.cm == cm
```

I can easily manage this if `page.cm` is a per-instance property set in `__init__`, but I need to call class methods on `cm.Page` which need access to the `cm` object, so it has to be a static property.

If I just set it as a static property on the `Page` class, it would end up affecting *other* `ContentManager`s pages as well, which is not desirable.

How would I achieve this? Metaclasses? Or some sort of class factory function?

Comment: You either make it an instance or a class attribute/property, there are no other choices even if you introduce metaclass magic. It rather seems that you need an instance attribute and some of your code should be moved from class methods to instance methods to have access to these instance variables.

Comment: Putting variables (non-const data) to static/global/shared/whatever places is a bad practice in general (even in other programming languages). It usually indicates unsuitable design that needs rethinking.

Comment: I do think you're right, but given the (lack of) importance and small scope of the project, I decided it would be worth it if it was achievable.

Comment: Playing with metaclasses and dynamic hacks is fun, but in my experience its often better to avoid using them in most projects. They have use only in case of low level framework code when you have to intercept class creation. If you go with creating a subclass every time in your `__init__` then I would use the class syntax. Calling the metaclass (`type` in this case) directly to create a class object is usually uglier. "Executing a class declaration" does the same under the hood: it calls the metaclass with parameters parsed from your class declaration to create a class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be creating a subclass of `Page` for every `ContentManage` instance:

```
class Page:
    cm = None

    def __init__(self, title, content):
        self.title = title
        self.content = content


class ContentManager:
    def __init__(self, root_url):
        class PerContentManagerPage(Page):
            cm = self

        self.Page = PerContentManagerPage


page0 = Page(title='Test Page', content='hello world!')

cm = ContentManager(root_url='//localhost')
page = cm.Page(title='Test Page', content='hello world!')

cm2 = ContentManager(root_url='//localhost')
page2 = cm2.Page(title='Test Page 2', content='hello world!')

assert page0.cm is None
assert page.cm == cm
assert page2.cm == cm2
```

In python a class is also an object (an instance of its metaclass). This solution creates a new subclass of `Page` every time you instantiate `ContentManager`. This means that the `cm.Page` class isn't the same as the `cm2.Page` class but both are the subclasses of `Page`. This is why it's possible that `cm.Page.cm` and `cm2.Page.cm` have different values, because these are two separate classes (or class objects).

Note: Although in python this could be solved by creating subclass objects dynamically, problems usually have better solutions. Creating classes/subclasses dynamically is a warning sign (*HACK*).

I'm still convinced that you shouldn't create a page subclass for each content manager instance. Instead I would simply use instances of the global `ContentManager` and `Page` classes by connecting them with references to each other in a suitable way and putting the data and the code into instance attributes/methods.

Answer (score 1):

Setting everything else aside, you'll just need to dynamically construct a class to tie to each instance of `ContentManager`; we can do this using the built-in `type` function, which can either, with one argument, give us the type of an object, or, with three arguments (class name, base classes, and class dictionary) construct a new class.

Here's a sample of how that might look in your situation:

```
class Page(object):
    # This is just a default value if we construct a Page
    # outside the context of a ContentManager
    cm = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @classmethod
    def do_class_thing(cls):
        return cls.cm

class ContentManager(object):

    def __init__(self, root_url):
        self.url = root_url

        """
        This is where the magic happens. We're telling type() to
        construct a class, with the class name ContentManagerPage,
        have it inherit from the above explicitly-declared Page
        class, and then overriding its __dict__ such that the class
        cm variable is set to be the ContentManager we're
        constructing it from.
        """

        self.Page = type(str('ContentManagerPage'), (Page,), {'cm': self})
```

Once you've got all this set up, it's simple enough to do exactly what you're trying to do, with cm as a class variable.

Comment: Are there any practical differences between using the `type` function and defining the class itself inside the `__init__` method?

Comment: Nope! Completely stylistic.